# HQL statement works with Persistence Query, not with Hibernate @Formula

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpa-2.0

Inside a Hibernate entity, i try to retrieve a Set of entities with @Formula

```
@Formula(value = "SELECT entityA from EntityA entityA "
        + "INNER JOIN entityA.id listValue WHERE listValue.id   "
        + "in ( select entityB.listValueId from EntityB entityB  where entityB.companyId  "
        + "in ( select entityC.id from EntityC entityC where entityC.id = '162B7E74-713C-4565-AAD2-52EC57B07419') )")
private Set<EntityA> entityASet;
```

Unfortunately this returns the following strange error:

> org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | Table
>   'schema.**ENTITY_C_TABLE_ENTITY_A_TABLE**' doesn't exist

Note here that **ENTITY_C_TABLE_ENTITY_A_TABLE** is a combination name of the EntityC (DB Table: ENTITY_C_TABLE) , EntityA (DB Table ENTITY_A_TABLE) and there is **NO** such table in the database

The strange part is that when i execute the exact same query with the following code, it returns the results correctly with no errors:

```
String query = "SELECT entityA from EntityA entityA "
        + "INNER JOIN entityA.id listValue WHERE listValue.id   "
        + "in ( select entityB.listValueId from EntityB entityB  where entityB.companyId  "
        + "in ( select entityC.id from EntityC entityC where entityC.id = '162B7E74-713C-4565-AAD2-52EC57B07419') )";

Query qb = em.createQuery(query);
List<EntityA> resultList = qb.getResultList();
```

I struggle to understand why when the same HQL is used inside a Formula does not work and generates such a weird DB table naming, while when executed separately it returns results. 
I saw some answers suggesting the following property in the persistence.xml, but this did not solve anything:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

PS. I am aware that Hibernate 5.1 allows joins to unrelated entities, but i use a lower version, so i had to go with a solution with a "where" clause

Comment: Seems to me that, for some reason, the Hibernate is trying to find a ManyToMany table between `ENTITY_C_TABLE` and `ENTITY_A_TABLE`. This could explain the error for `ENTITY_C_TABLE_ENTITY_A_TABLE`. Can you show your entity mapping?